# Impala: convert dd-MMM-yy string to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: string, date, casting, impala

I'm receiving a csv with dates in a dd-MMM-yy format, e.g.

> 29-aug-17

I want to convert them into yyyy-MM-dd, e.g.

> 2017-08-29

It could be just me not having googled the correct function, but I can't find anything to cope with the MMM way of writing months, unless I used a lookup / case statement and split the string and put it back together.

If anyone could suggest a better way that would be great, I'm sure there must be one!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer is:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('29-aug-17', 'dd-MMM-yy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

Run these query in impala to get desired results:

`select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('29-aug-17','dd-MMM-yy'),'yyyy-MM-dd');`

or

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('29-aug-17','dd-MMM-yy')));
```